# Recording websocket messages

Tags: websocket, iptables, recorder

I need to extend a HTTP recorder to record websocket traffic. HTTP recorder is in C / unix platform.

I know HTTP traffic will be through port 80 or 443, hence I am able to record it. In HTTP message a new port is communicated, and through that port websocket traffic passes through. Since this port is dynamic, and HTTP messages will be different in different cases I can not parse and get port for websocket.

I think of below logic, not sure if that is going to work. Need your suggestion / pointers in this regard.

Make use of iptables

Forward all the traffic to a different port (where my application is listening) using iptable rules

Then my application should receive the data (hope it is possible)

Then my application should receive the destination information (when data is forwarded from iptables to my application, can I get actual destination ip/port).

Assuming, I get actual ip/port, then from my application, I can send data to actual destination.

I know, its a long way to go, will this approach work.

Comment: "*I know HTTP traffic will be through port 80 or 443*" - *typically*, but not *always*. Those are the *standard* ports, but an HTTP server can use any port it wants. A non-standard port must be specified explicitly in any URL used to access that server.

Comment: "*In HTTP message a new port is communicated, and through that port websocket traffic passes through. Since this port is dynamic, and HTTP messages will be different in different cases I can not parse and get port for websocket*" - HTTP itself has no association with WebSocket. Typically, an HTTP message would contain HTML that uses scripting to construct a `WebSocket` object, passing it a `ws:` or `wss:` URL to connect to the WebSocket server. In that case, you could simply parse the HTML's scripting looking for those URLs, then you would know both the hostname and the port.

Comment: This "ws:" or "wss:" part is really useful. I will examine contents of HTTP messages and see if this can be implemented.

Comment: just note that an HTML page's scripting might be embedded directly in the HTML itself, or it may be at a separate URL that the HTML refers to.  So you might need to make multiple HTTP requests to discover the WebSocket address being connected to.